# Find all lat/long's that exist within an irregular shaped city perimeter

Tags: mysql, database, google-maps

looking for some help here.

I'm looking to build a MySQL database query that will find match known lat/long's within an irregular shape (the bounding area of a city)

An example of such an area would be the perimeter of Salt Lake City, UT: https://www.google.com/maps?q=Salt+Lake+City,+UT&hl=en&sll=39.499761,-111.547028&sspn=7.585439,16.907959&hnear=Salt+Lake+City,+Salt+Lake,+Utah&t=m&z=12

I have stuff that will search a radius around the middle point, but I'm not sure if I can search to the exact borders.

I have all of Google Maps' API data cached locally available for query, but I assume I only need the lat/long of each value.

Help! :)

Comment: Have you looked into MySQL's [spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/spatial-extensions.html), especially its [`ST_Contains()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_st-contains) and [`ST_Within()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_st-within) functions?

Comment: "*I have all of Google Maps' API data cached locally available for query*" - you may wish to verify that you are not in violation of the [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms), especially clause [10.1.3](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3)(b) "No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content".